# Rails images and assets not being loaded properly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, in my Rails application I have something like:

```
.wax_seal {
  background: url("wax-seal-small.png");
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 92px;
}

.wax_seal:active {
  background: url('wax-seal-small-broken.png');
}
```

And in my `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

I manually invoke the compiling of assets:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And the files are created with hashes at the end of the name:

```
wax-seal-small-Uuhqwduhqwdoi234983jewf.png
```

---

So this doesn't work:

```
background: url("wax-seal-small.png");
```

But this works fine (when I **manually** type it in Chrome):

```
background: url("wax-seal-small-Uuhqwduhqwdoi234983jewf.png");
```

---

What step am I missing here? How can I make my CSS rules add in that little hash?

Adding `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` makes it work, but I read in the Rails guide that it's a bad practice due to significant performance hits.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and I've tried both of the suggestions in the 2 answers (so far) with no luck. Can you share your entire `production.rb` file so I can compare with mine? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this in edgerails documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

> 2.3.2 CSS and Sass
>
> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.
>
> - `image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)`
> - `image-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png"`
>
> The more generic form can also be used but the asset path and class must both be specified:
>
> - `asset-url("rails.png", image) becomes url(/assets/rails.png)`
> - `asset-path("rails.png", image) becomes "/assets/rails.png"`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer? The question seems to be "why is fingerprinting not working".

Answer (score 4):

If you're using sass or less you can use `background: image-url("wax-seal-small.png");`

That will prepend the path to your file and append the cache buster hash.

Otherwise just reference it to the /assets directory. E.g. `background: url("/assets/wax-seal-small.png");`

Comment: I'm using the default `.scss` files. Is that the kosher, rail's way to do this? Using `image-url` instead of `url`? Where can I find official documentation on `image-url`?