# Application.css file will not display logo in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm fairly new to development and have been focusing a lot of time on a web project in Ruby on Rails. I'm having some problems with my `application.css` file.

As I understand it, this file will be used to apply the basic layout to all my views. So, I would like to add my website logo to the top left of the page.I currently have the image stored in my `public` folder while my `application.css` file is located in `/app/assets/stylesheets` folder. I've tried numerous ways to get this to work with no success.

Here's what I have in the `.css` file:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("../public/tpllogo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    font-family: 'Courier New', courier, monospace;
 }
```

All other changes I have made to this css test fine (with some minor issues of updating after changes).

Comment: where is your logo.png file located?

Comment: `url("../tpllogo.png");`

Comment: This question already answered. Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877353/rails-images-and-assets-not-being-loaded-properly

Comment: It's in my public folder.

Answer (score 1):

just change `background-image: url("../public/tpllogo.png");` to
`background-image: image-url('tpllogo.png');`

Comment: So you agree that this should be closed as a duplicate of the question this was marked a duplicate of? (hint: duplicates should not be answered)

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this, the easiest way is with Bootstrap.

First add this line to /app/assets/javascripts/applications.js exactly as follows

```
//= require bootstrap
```

If the Bootstrap Sass gem is not included:
Add the following line to your Gemfile -

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.0.3.0'
```

Once you've done that add the following line to (if the file doesnt exist, create it) - /assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Now that you're all set up **you can add a nav bar, that will keep your logo where you want it** 
view this example from the bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

The important part for your logo is this line:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question being asked?

Comment: logo placement, css, sass, compilation & pre-compilation.

Comment: You get that the problem is the background image isn't loading, right?  How is adding Bootstrap going to solve that?

Comment: No, I read it as a css placement issue. At no point did @Misanthropos say the image wasnt loading.

Comment: Even if that is true, adding Bootstrap is an overkill for something that barely takes more than 3 lines of CSS.  (related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: Well thats most certainly an opinion. This person explains their a noob so we shouldn't be accepting their {background-position: left top;}  as a good way to place the logo on a website. SO community is supposed to be about helping, explaining, & learning.