# bootstrap-sass not working in production with apache server fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

I have searched and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271696/cant-get-css-working-on-heroku-using-rails-4-with-bootstrap-saas-gem/17082720#17082720) post with a similar problem only with Heroku instead of apache.

My gem file is very similar, application was working fine in development env but when I switch to production, apache server would stop rendering all of the bootstrap-sass goodies.

The only thing that I had to do to fix it was setting following production environments as suggested by user2481435:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me get a better understanding of what exactly I have done there (i.e. what those 4 settings are responsible for).

P.S.
Along with this post I am searching for a good source where I can get an insight into environments settings. If there is someone there who can leave a linkie to a good book or an article, documentation please by all means do so.

Cheers

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: no I did not... problem fixed when I changed the mentioned config settings. I am just wondering if anyone can shed some light on what those settings are