# rails 4 problems pushing on heroku - invalid CSS - bootstrap expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

To make it short, I am using this CSS code in my app:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md;) {
    div.content-wrap-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

works fine on localhost. It is simply hiding a div when the resolution goes below XYpx. According to the Bootstrap docu, this is valid CSS code: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Now, when pushing on heroku I get this:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...ia (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@screen-md;) {"
```

What do I do wrong?
I've followed this answer here to configure my production.rb:
[Can't get CSS working on Heroku using Rails 4 with bootstrap-sass gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271696/cant-get-css-working-on-heroku-using-rails-4-with-bootstrap-saas-gem?answertab=votes#tab-top)

like this:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then pushing again to heroku?

there is more info on Rails Asset Pipeline on Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

It worked for me, hope it helps

Comment: sorry was to fast accepting the answer. unfortunately that did not help. still working perfect on dev but not on production

Comment: After solving my error I was missing just this! Thanks @Jax700303